# Is it possible to push XML file(Load the Data) to SQL Server via SSIS (Visual Studio) without XSD file?

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis, xsd

Question 1: is it possible to push only XML file to SQL Server via SSIS (Visual Studio) without XSD file?

Question 2: is it possible to push only XML file to SQL Server without XSD?

If yes, how can we process it, and any guidance or link would be helpful.

If no, what would be the reason, Why we cannot push the XML file to DB without XSD?

I surfed the net more than 6 hours, I couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Why not store XML content as string?

Comment: Hey @Hasan, I'm new this, I will try what you suggested. But is it possible of what I mentioned in the question?

Comment: Tbh, i don't know if it's possible or not but I can tell you I have never seen xml stored as file in sql database.

Comment: Not like store as a file. Store the content of xml file on SQL Server, that is it. And sorry for miscommunication.

Comment: Simma, it's possible. Please see my answer. There are well-known methods for this.

Comment: @Simma, please edit your post and add missing details. One of missing things, we don't know what is the objective: (1) shred XML, or (2) load XML file in its entirety into one single column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server you can convert a text representing XML as you please, like:

```
CONVERT(XML, N'somexml', 2)
```

In the code above replace `somexml` with your XML. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/create-xml-data-type-variables-and-columns?view=sql-server-ver15) provide a nice example about how you can specify XML as a type of a column:

```
CREATE TABLE T (XmlColumn xml default N'<element1/><element2/>');
```

Before you continue reading, try experimenting by the creation of the table above and inserting XML into it, as:

```
insert into T(xml)
values(N'<element1/><element2/>');
```

Now, if your tests confirm that you are able to convert a text into XML in the way shown above, then the only thing remaining is to convert whatever XML you have in your application code into a text. I do not know what your application code/framework is, but this is how you can do it with C#:

https://forums.asp.net/t/1630414.aspx?How+to+convert+XML+to+Text+file+using+C+

Comment: Thanks for the answer @lajos, I'm going through the article which you mentioned.

Comment: @Simma you are welcome. I also recommend doing some very short and simple experiments directly on your MS SQL either in command-line or a helper tool, like SSMS.